# Docker servers exception

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker

i have installed Docker and i made up my .yml file which is:

```
    version: '3'

services:
  zoekeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ZOEKEEPER_CONNECT: zoekeeper:2181

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:17017"
    restart: unless-stopped

  mysql:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

I've builded with docker-compose and the mongo and kafka servers ran well.
When started the Spring Boot app locally - this is what occurs:

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

I want to run the MySQL server also and put my app in the image.
Anyone can help
?

Comment: What is the connection string for your java application?

Comment: I am running the servers only via docker.
My app is runned from the local machine or this just cannot happen?
You mean that i should make an image of my app also?

Comment: That wasn't the question. What is your database connection string?

Comment: @OneCricketeer `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp`

Comment: @TarunLalwani i've posted it in the comment above

Answer (score 0):

FIXED!
The error was in my .yml file:

> `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD = 1`
> for the MySQL error

Comment: You should read the mysql docker documentation about how to add a user and password. Don't connect as root using no password. Same goes for Mongo